# how to manage requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe

I made a function that scrambles and translates some texts.
It works ok as long as you wait to the end of the animation and then mouseover to other elements, but if you rush to the next one, the previous animation stops.

```js
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("#menu li"),
  navMenuText = document.querySelectorAll("#menu li a"),
  translation = document.querySelectorAll("#translation li"),
  originalEnglish = [];
originalJapanese = [];

navMenuText.forEach((e) => {
  originalEnglish.push(e.innerHTML);
});
translation.forEach((e) => {
  originalJapanese.push(e.innerHTML);
});

let target;
let frame = 0;
let frame2 = 0;
let singleText;
let singleText2;

let callbackId;

const glitch = ["-", "+", "=", `[`, `;`, "#", "%", "^", "*", "_"];

let times;

let isRunning = false;

navMenu.forEach((e) => {
  // });
  e.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    target = [].slice.call(navMenu).indexOf(e);

    if (!navMenu[target].classList.contains("trasnlated")) {
      navMenu[target].classList.add("trasnlated");

      singleText = originalEnglish[target].split("");
      times = singleText.length * 2;
      frame = 0;

      function glitchTranslation() {
        if (frame < times + translation[target].innerHTML.length) {
          if (frame < times) {
            singleText[Math.floor(Math.random() * singleText.length)] =
              glitch[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
            navMenuText[target].innerHTML = singleText.join("");
          } else {
            singleText[frame - times] =
              translation[target].innerHTML[frame - times];

            navMenuText[target].innerHTML = singleText
              .join("")
              .slice(0, translation[target].innerHTML.length);
          }
          isRunning = true;
          callbackId = requestAnimationFrame(glitchTranslation);
        } else if (frame === times + translation[target].innerHTML.length) {
          isRunning = false;
        }
        frame++;
      }
      glitchTranslation();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#menu li {
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="trigger1"><a href="#">something</a></li>
      <li id="trigger3"><a href="#">earth</a><span class="bar"></span></li>
      <li id="trigger4">
        <a href="about.html">human</a><span class="bar"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="trigger6">
        <a href="#">contact</a><span class="bar"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="translation" style="display: none">
      <li>なにか</li>
      <li>地球</li>
      <li>人間</li>
      <li>お問い合わせ</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/JavascriptIsANightmare/pen/JjWoqVM

Comment: Hi! Please put your runnable example **here, on-site**, not just offsite. Four reasons: It's easy to accidentally leave something essential out when you rely on off-site examples; people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: You can put your example onsite using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: (And no, JavaScript is not a nightmare. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your variable declarations inside the `mouseover` handler so they are scopped and that the next event won't override them:

```js
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("#menu li"),
  navMenuText = document.querySelectorAll("#menu li a"),
  translation = document.querySelectorAll("#translation li"),
  originalEnglish = [],
  originalJapanese = [];

navMenuText.forEach((e) => {
  originalEnglish.push(e.innerHTML);
});
translation.forEach((e) => {
  originalJapanese.push(e.innerHTML);
});

const glitch = ["-", "+", "=", `[`, `;`, "#", "%", "^", "*", "_"];

navMenu.forEach((e) => {
  // });
  e.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {

    // move all the variables declarations inside the mouseover handler
    let target;
    let frame = 0;
    let frame2 = 0;
    let singleText;
    let singleText2;

    let callbackId;
    let times;

    let isRunning = false;


    target = [].slice.call(navMenu).indexOf(e);

    if (!navMenu[target].classList.contains("trasnlated")) {
      navMenu[target].classList.add("trasnlated");

      singleText = originalEnglish[target].split("");
      times = singleText.length * 2;
      frame = 0;

      function glitchTranslation() {
        if (frame < times + translation[target].innerHTML.length) {
          if (frame < times) {
            singleText[Math.floor(Math.random() * singleText.length)] =
              glitch[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
            navMenuText[target].innerHTML = singleText.join("");
          } else {
            singleText[frame - times] =
              translation[target].innerHTML[frame - times];

            navMenuText[target].innerHTML = singleText
              .join("")
              .slice(0, translation[target].innerHTML.length);
          }
          isRunning = true;
          callbackId = requestAnimationFrame(glitchTranslation);
        } else if (frame === times + translation[target].innerHTML.length) {
          isRunning = false;
        }
        frame++;
      }
      glitchTranslation();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#menu li {
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="trigger1"><a href="#">something</a></li>
      <li id="trigger3"><a href="#">earth</a><span class="bar"></span></li>
      <li id="trigger4">
        <a href="about.html">human</a><span class="bar"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="trigger6">
        <a href="#">contact</a><span class="bar"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="translation" style="display: none">
      <li>なにか</li>
      <li>地球</li>
      <li>人間</li>
      <li>お問い合わせ</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```